# Grouping with strongly type group key in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, wpf-4.0, igrouping

Every example and I article I found, is about grouping items by one property and displaying it. But what I have, is a strongly type group key, which I want to display. Here is models and grouping logic:

The item interface

```
public interface IItem {
    string Title { get; }
    string ToolTip { get; }
    object Icon { get; }
    Type GroupType { get; }
}
```

`IItem` has many implementations like this:

```
public class Item : IItem {
    public string Title { get; private set; }
    public string ToolTip { get; private set; }
    public object Icon { get; private set; }

    // I have many implementation of IGroup which I will use them in GroupType properties.
    public Type GroupType { get { return SomeGroupTypeHere; } }
}
```

And here is the group interface:

```
public interface IGroup {
    string Name { get; }
    object Icon { get; }
}
```

and it has many implementations too.

I collect them in my view model (by getting help from `Autofac`):

```
public class MyViewModel {

    private readonly IEnumerable<IGrouping<IGroup, IItem>> _items;

    public MyViewModel(IEnumerable<IGroup> groups, IEnumerable<IItem> items){
        _items = items.GroupBy(t => {
            var g = groups.First(u => u.GetType() == t.GroupType);
            return g;
        });
    }

    public IEnumerable<IGrouping<IGroup, IItem>> Items {
        get { return _items; }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is, how to display this grouped items, in a `ItemsControl`?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="20 20 20 0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <!-- here is my template that uses IItem properties, example: -->
            <Button Content="{Binding Title}"
                    ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
        </DataTemplate >
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The code, just only displays the first item in each group, and I have no idea what to do to show group headers (that use `IGroup` properties) and also show all items in each group. Any suggestion please? Any article or blog-post will be very useful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `HierarchicalDataTemplate` when you want to display Grouped data, Change your `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` to a `HierarchialDataTemplate'.

Sample (and Untested) HierarchialDataTemplate:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="20 20 20 0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <Button Content="{Binding Title}" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Button Content="{Binding Title}" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
                </DataTemplate >
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Refer to this [blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx) for step-by-step approach to HierarchialDataTemplates.

**UPDATE**

I have tried the above HierarchialDataTemplate with your code and it doesnt seem to work. However, if I replace `ItemsControl` with TreeView, it does work as expected.

So, I guess, you might want to have nested `ItemControl` for your case, Tested sample code as below:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="20 20 20 0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="{Binding Title}" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="15,0,0,0">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <Button Content="{Binding Title}" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
                        </DataTemplate >
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Here is the screen shot with this nested ItemsControls.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**
I think you need to update the template to display Group, the current template doesnt do that.

Updated Template is below:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="20 20 20 0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="{Binding Key.Name}" />
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="15,0,0,0">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <Button Content="{Binding Title}" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
                        </DataTemplate >
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And the resulting Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: it seems I have no choice exept using a nested `ItemsControl`. Thanks for answer. You got a +1. I'll wait a few hours for another answer, and then your one will be accepted probably. Thanks again.

Comment: it doesn't work ): instead of displaying group properties, it displays the first item in each group. The children are shown well; but not the group itself.

Comment: Updated template to bind to Group Key, instead of indvidual item.